\verse in a \caption
the following example gives a hail of error messages, also neither the
verse nor the reference are correctly formatted as part of a caption. Simply \protecting the verse does not help.
%%======================================================================
  % !Mode:: "TeX:UK:UTF-8"
  % !TEX program = XeLaTeX
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{caption}%formating captions of floats
\usepackage{graphicx}%inclusion of images
\usepackage{url}%typeset internet links (preloaded in beamer)

\begin{document}

\urldef{\Fontana}\url
{https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/32/Fontana_villa_borgh
ese.JPG}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{The \textit{Fontana dei Cavalli Marini} in the garden of the 
\textit{Villa Borghese} near Rome is an example for a dynamic 
equilibrium. It inspired the Swiss poet \textsc{Conrad Ferdinand Meyer} 
(1825--1898) to the well known poem ``Roman fountains'' (7th version of 
1882):
   \begin{verse}
     Rising high and falling, the jet \\
     fills a bowl of marble, \\
     which overflows, hidden in a mist, \\
     and fills a second bowl; \\
     the second gives, when it becomes to rich, \\
     the water to a third: \\
     and each takes and gives, \\
     and flows and rests.
   \end{verse}
  The image was taken from \Fontana\ visited 2024-05-07.}
 \label{fig:Fountains}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]
{Graphics/Fontana_dei_Cavalli_Marini}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

Are you able to provide code we can compile? You can use standard images like example-image or pass draft to graphicx.

Do you really want to put a poem in the table of contents and the figure caption or do you want to place it below the figure? In general you cannot pass verbatim text in the arguments of another command.

I don't think you want a poem in a caption. That's rather like a footnote, otherwise you'd place the poem in the text describing the image.
Here are two possibilities: one with a short caption for the list of figures, the other with a footnote-like treatment of the accompanying text.
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\urldef{\Fontana}%
  \url{https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/32/Fontana_villa_borghese.JPG}

\caption[The \emph{Fontana dei Cavalli Marini} in the garden of the 
\emph{Villa Borghese} near Rome]{The \emph{Fontana dei Cavalli Marini} in the 
garden of the \emph{Villa Borghese} near Rome is an example for a dynamic 
equilibrium. It inspired the Swiss poet \textsc{Conrad Ferdinand Meyer} 
(1825--1898) to the well known poem ``Roman fountains'' (7th version of 
1882):\par\vspace{\topsep}
   \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
   \begin{verse}
     Rising high and falling, the jet \\
     fills a bowl of marble, \\
     which overflows, hidden in a mist, \\
     and fills a second bowl; \\
     the second gives, when it becomes to rich, \\
     the water to a third: \\
     and each takes and gives, \\
     and flows and rests.
   \end{verse}
  \end{varwidth}
  \par\vspace{\topsep}
The image was taken from \Fontana\ visited 2024-05-07.}
\label{fig:Fountains}

\centering
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}%Graphics/Fontana_dei_Cavalli_Marini}

\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}%Graphics/Fontana_dei_Cavalli_Marini}

\caption{The \emph{Fontana dei Cavalli Marini} in the garden of the 
\emph{Villa Borghese}}
\label{fig:Fountains-revisited}

\bigskip\footnotesize

The \emph{Fontana dei Cavalli Marini} in the 
garden of the \emph{Villa Borghese} near Rome is an example for a dynamic 
equilibrium. It inspired the Swiss poet \textsc{Conrad Ferdinand Meyer} 
(1825--1898) to the well known poem ``Roman fountains'' (7th version of 
1882):
   \begin{verse}
     Rising high and falling, the jet \\
     fills a bowl of marble, \\
     which overflows, hidden in a mist, \\
     and fills a second bowl; \\
     the second gives, when it becomes to rich, \\
     the water to a third: \\
     and each takes and gives, \\
     and flows and rests.
   \end{verse}
The image was taken from
\url{https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/32/Fontana_villa_borghese.JPG}
visited 2024-05-07.

\end{figure}

\end{document}



yes, thanks, this works

You can put the caption in a box, but you will certainly want to provide an alternate caption if using links or a table of contents.
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{caption}%formating captions of floats
\usepackage{graphicx}%inclusion of images
\usepackage{url}%typeset internet links (preloaded in beamer)

\begin{document}

\urldef{\Fontana}\url
{https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/32/Fontana_villa_borgh
ese.JPG}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{The \textit{Fontana dei Cavalli Marini} in the garden of the 
    \textit{Villa Borghese} near Rome is an example for a dynamic 
    equilibrium. It inspired the Swiss poet \textsc{Conrad Ferdinand Meyer} 
    (1825--1898) to the well known poem ``Roman fountains'' (7th version of 
    1882):
    \begin{verse}
      Rising high and falling, the jet \\
      fills a bowl of marble, \\
      which overflows, hidden in a mist, \\
      and fills a second bowl; \\
      the second gives, when it becomes to rich, \\
      the water to a third: \\
      and each takes and gives, \\
      and flows and rests.
    \end{verse}
    The image was taken from \Fontana\ visited 2024-05-07.}}
  \label{fig:Fountains}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]
  {example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

My images suck right now, but you will also want to adjust the spacing. Usually, captions go at the bottom in figures and caption expects this. If you are putting all or some at the top, you should let caption know this so the space can be adjusted appropriately.

